# Diagnosing why a file now causes Blender to crash

Tags: linked-data

I was working on materials just before this file started causing Blender to crash when it tries to open it. By moving it to another folder, which causes all the many files it's linked to to no longer load, the file can be opened.

When it does, the last material I worked on is in the shader editor, but missing some changes so maybe I forgot to save them. Without those changes, the material is identical to another one in all but name, pulling the same image textures. I think making those changes to the material was the last thing I was doing before it stopped working.

I have disabled all add-ons besides the standard ones, and it still crashes.

When I move the file back to the folder where it is supposed to be and open Blender from a terminal, these are the errors listed at the end of the loading log:

```
ERROR (bke.anim_sys): /home/sources/buildbot-x86_64-slave/linux_glibc217_x86_64_cmake/blender.git/source/blender/blenkernel/intern/anim_sys.c:4153 BKE_animsys_eval_driver: invalid driver - nodes["Mapping"].max[0]
ERROR (bke.anim_sys): /home/sources/buildbot-x86_64-slave/linux_glibc217_x86_64_cmake/blender.git/source/blender/blenkernel/intern/anim_sys.c:4153 BKE_animsys_eval_driver: invalid driver - nodes["Mapping"].min[0]
ERROR (bke.anim_sys): /home/sources/buildbot-x86_64-slave/linux_glibc217_x86_64_cmake/blender.git/source/blender/blenkernel/intern/anim_sys.c:4153 BKE_animsys_eval_driver: invalid driver - nodes["Mapping"].use_max[0]
ERROR (bke.anim_sys): /home/sources/buildbot-x86_64-slave/linux_glibc217_x86_64_cmake/blender.git/source/blender/blenkernel/intern/anim_sys.c:4153 BKE_animsys_eval_driver: invalid driver - nodes["Mapping"].min[0]
ERROR (bke.anim_sys): /home/sources/buildbot-x86_64-slave/linux_glibc217_x86_64_cmake/blender.git/source/blender/blenkernel/intern/anim_sys.c:4153 BKE_animsys_eval_driver: invalid driver - nodes["Mapping"].max[0]
Writing: /tmp/MoonTown_Master.crash.txt
Segmentation fault (core dumped)
```

And the end of MoonTown_Master.crash.txt is:

```
# backtrace
./blender(BLI_system_backtrace+0x1d) [0x14ee85d]
./blender() [0x12cbb79]
/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6(+0x3ef20) [0x7f0a2f158f20]
./blender() [0x2cff8c6]
./blender(workbench_deferred_draw_scene+0x70) [0x2d2d690]
./blender() [0x2d2a31b]
./blender(DRW_draw_render_loop_ex+0x274) [0x2cf8b64]
./blender(view3d_main_region_draw+0x77) [0x2fd70f7]
./blender(ED_region_do_draw+0x8f1) [0x304b991]
./blender(wm_draw_update+0x496) [0x16a0696]
./blender(WM_main+0x30) [0x169dcf0]
./blender(main+0x2fe) [0x1237f7e]
/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6(__libc_start_main+0xe7) [0x7f0a2f13bb97]
./blender() [0x12c849c]
```

The file is over 300 MB and is full of links to other files. I don't know that it would be useful for me to strip it down, I will if that helps diagnose this and can be done in a way that doesn't erase the issue that's causing this. How can I proceed to get this file working again?

Though, if you are willing to make a 450 MB download, you can get this repo and it should have everything to exactly reproduce the problem:

https://github.com/briligg/Moonwards-Assets/tree/test-broken-master-file

Comment: Have you tried removing the driver from the mapping node before moving it back to the target folder?

Comment: @RobertGützkow No, i don't know how to do that. Also, i'm not sure it is a good idea.

Comment: Sorry if that wasn't clear, I'm talking about the (animation) driver on the mapping nodes properties that produce the errors `ERROR (bke.anim_sys)`, not an actual hardware driver. If you're able to open a copy of the original project when placed in a different location, then you should be able to simply right click on the purple colored fields of the mapping node and select *Delete Driver*.

Comment: You mean the mapping node from the shader editor? I can't find any material that has a mapping node. I was setting one up for the last material I was working on, but that wasn't saved. At least, it doesn't show up in the shader editor. No other material that isn't a linked material has a mapping node either, and precious few of those do. I tried eliminating all recent materials but couldn't stop the crashing.

Comment: Okay, deleting that material stopped the crashing. I guess i'd only done that in linked files, not in this file. I suppose it was stopped by isolating it from the image textures it tried to load, so that it didn't get to whatever was causing it to hang on an operation.

Comment: Maybe i should also mention i'd never put a driver on anything. So, maybe there was some file corruption during the last save for some reason.

Comment: Would be great to find the cause. Can you by any chance reduce it to a minimal file, now that you know the crash is tied to the material? I think the developers would appreciate this very much

Comment: Really? Sure, I guess I can do that. And post it here? I don't know that this qualifies as a bug, but i can post it as such if it does.

Comment: Hm. If i delete any part of that file and then return it to the folder it came from, it opens without crashing. But, if i return the original file and try to open it, it crashes Blender. I don't know what to say.

Comment: If I try to open the Master.blend you posted on github I get a "file not supported" error

Comment: @cegaton - Ah, i didn't think about people downloading just the file in question instead of the whole repo - yes, that does make more sense now that the issue is identified. You want Models/ Locations/ MoonTown_Master. Pardon me.

Comment: @ki I get the same error

Comment: oh. Well, Master.blend is really old and i should eliminate it. It's just a legacy thing i keep around for no reason.

Comment: Models/ Locations/ MoonTown_Master

Comment: Same thing "file format is not supported".

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/102737/discussion-between-cegaton-and-kim-holder-wants-monica-back).